# Receiving external Webhooks in Heroku

Tags: heroku, webhooks, heroku-postgres

I'd like to receive web hooks in Heroku from a third-party app and perform an action upon reception (a simple Rest API request). I'm a bit of a beginner in this.

I've followed [Heroku's guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-webhooks), assuming that at the end I would get an endpoint URL similar to what I get on https://webhook.site/51856771-66ef-4fbd-b293-dc1f24e3581a and that I'll be ready to start building my API call, but it wasn't the case.

I found what I believe to be my Endpoint URL: `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/webhooks` but my webhooks are being welcomed by a `403 Forbidden`.

Now I assume this is a security to avoid unsollicited and excessive calls, but I don't understand how to get past it.
I can indeed see a `webhook_secret` in the Config Vars of my Heroku app hosting the webhook endpoint, but I am unsure if this is what I am looking for, nor how to implement it in order to "whitelist" the web hooks I want to subscribe to.

The app I want to receive webhooks from has a "signature" system inside the payload, but it does not allow to add a secret key in that payload.

Heroku's guides seem to be specific to web hooks sent from Heroku hosted apps and their API only, and I wasn't able to find resources relevant to my issue (or at least, nothing at a Beginner level).

Comment: That guide is for webhooks that Heroku _generates_. If you want to _receive_ webhooks in your app, you need to write code to do so. What technology are you using to build your app?

Comment: thanks for the answer @Chris  
The app is really small (it contains 2 Rest API requests pretty much) using Golang wrappers

Comment: Okay, so you need to add another endpoint to receive the webhook. Webhooks are just HTTP requests.

Comment: Okay thanks! I did some research based on your response and will look into the Gorilla package which seem to be recommended. I'll dig into it, thanks!